# proxy_pass Nginx / to Tomcat app

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a SSL-ed Tomcat web App running with context-paht `/abc`，and I have a subdomain `abc.example.com`. Here is my Nginx config:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  listen       [::]:80;
  server_name  abc.example.com;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html/abc;

  include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

  location / {
      proxy_pass https://tomcat:8443/abc/;
  }

}
```

I want let Nginx reverse proxy this web app in Tomcat, when I visit `abc.example.com` the request proxy to backend Tomcat.

This config seems did not work as the static files like `css、imgs` can not be loaded（static files are placed in Tomcat）.

Comment: So you want the static content such as CSS and images to be returned by nginx but the rest to be proxied to tomcat?

Comment: @inneedofhelp Actually I want static files returned by Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the context of the tomcat app and the location in Nginx not matching. Either have your application in root context or do the pass within the matching location.

If both isn't an option you will need to rewrite the path before passing it on to the tomcat.